# P4Merge forgets my comparison method preference. How do I set a default value?

Tags: settings, perforce, p4merge

When running P4Merge, the comparison method is always initially set to 'Recognize line ending and white space differences' (aka all changes). I want to use 'Ignore line ending and white space length differences', but I have to manually re-set this every time the tool runs.

I have changed the setting:

- with the toolbar button
- in the preferences dialog
- on the File menu

and it never sticks. In fact, the preferences dialog entry is reset every time I go back to the menu, without even closing the program. I have changed the setting before using the Exit command from the File menu and before closing the window, and also before saving a merge.

In the past I was able to save my setting and have it be remembered, unfortunately I don't have any recollection of the software version involved. I was using P4Merge as standalone and none of the rest of the Perforce suite was installed.

I can update with any other supporting information that might prove relevant.

[Edit: It's the radio button setting in the preferences dialog that ignores changes and resets every time it's viewed, not the File submenu.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this issue was fixed in 2013.3.  I ran into this issue, updated to the latest version of P4, and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Unix/Linux, I would blow away the `.p4merge` directory in your home directory, which stores all your preferences.  In Windows, I'm sure there is a similar directory in your home folder.  Sometimes things can get out of sorts in that directory, and cleaning it out could help.  After doing so, try saving your preferences again (do it via `Edit -> Preferences` to change the defaults) and restarting p4merge.

If that doesn't work, it could be a buggy version.

Comment: In Windows, the preferences file is `%userprofile%\.p4merge\ApplicationSettings.xml`

Comment: Rev. P4Merge/NTX64/2013.2/661179, on 64-bit Windows 7 like the version string hints at. There did not exist a .p4merge directory in my profile, so I created it and set preferences again; still no luck.